# Does Qt ObjectName() have to be unique?

Tags: qt, pyqt

Simple question as in the title - if I call `setObjectName()` on an object, does it have to be unique, or is it just recommended because of convention? I've subclassed `QLabel`, and want to automatically give the objects created a name; if this is a bad idea, I'll find some way of setting a random unique name. (I'm actually using PyQt, but this shouldn't influence the answer!)

**Update**

In response to the 2 answers so far (which I should have predicted!), I want to do this so that I can ignore all instances of my subclass.  Calling `findChildren(QLabel)` cascades so that all subclasses of `QLabel` are also found - if I use the same object name for all my subclassed objects, then I can just regex in the 2nd argument of `findChildren()` so that I ignore them

Comment: no it doean't have to be unique, but it is recommended. This may be problematic when you search some item by its name or when you use style sheets.

Comment: `QObject::findChildren` returns a `List` of children with a matching name, so having duplicate names is indeed possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) for QObject, you can see that it states: -

> This property holds the name of this object.
>   You can find an object by name (and type) using findChild(). You can find a set of objects with **findChildren()**.

Looking at [findChildren()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren), it states: -

> Returns **all children of this object with the given name** that can be cast to type T...

So, clearly it can be seen that multiple objects can have the same name.

Answer (score 3):

No, but without unique names you wouldn't be able to find objects by name (without additional checks).

Answer (score 1):

Setting an object name is not strictly needed, it defaults to an empty string.
However, if you need to find objects by their name, you surely want it to be unique!

Answer (score 1):

The object name is essentially not used anywhere important. It's up to you how you set it up. There are two things of note:

1. Objects created by `setupUi` function in code generated by uic: all objects have names, and the names are unique. It's for your convenience only, though.
2. When using `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` on an object, all slots named `on_foo_bar` will be connected to a child object's `bar` signal, as long as the object is named `foo`.
3. When using CSS stylesheets for widgets (`QWidget` class hierarchy), the object names can be used as ids in id selectors. That's handy sometimes.

Comment: If you use Qt CSS to style objects, object names could be used in a selector, which is rather convenient.

Answer (score 0):

sharing the same name is good for automate styling too:

imagine you have 100 buttons, is a headache having to set stylesheet for each one... instead you can:

#menuPbts {
"backgroundcolor: red;"
"color: white;"
"font: bold 13px Rubik;" }

and set the name "menuPbts" to all your buttons...