# How to switch window to another class in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two classes made with pyqt like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(409, 119)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 61, 20))
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 221, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 50, 221, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 75, 81))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 61, 20))
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 61, 20))
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 221, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Password"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "login"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Email"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "distinct num"))


class Ui_Dialog2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(485, 429)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 461, 281))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 121, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 330, 211, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 391, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 350, 61, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 390, 461, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "process"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "file"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "select"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "push"))
```

These two classes have different window sizes and many different things.
How can I switch between two windows based on the login button of Ui_Dialog?
I know how to trigger on the login button but I don't know how to switch to another class.

I want to move to individual dialogs rather than being done in one dialog.

Comment: didnt know that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364295/does-qt-objectname-have-to-be-unique -->  clearly it can be seen that multiple objects can have the same name.

Comment: one way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280815/pyqt-window-focus